# How can I get QoS over a WDS bridge on Cisco WAP551

Tags: cisco, wifi, qos, wireless-bridge

I have two Cisco WAP551 devices bridging two physical locations wirelessly across the street from each other (200 feet, line-of-sight through a window). This is replacing a much, much older wireless bridge that has been rock solid as far as reliability. The new bridge is functioning great, however VoIP quality has gone completely out the window over this bridge. I tried to set up some quality of service, but I am unsure how it works here. It seems either the QoS doesnt function on the WDS VAP, or the built in QoS queue for voice data is not picking up my VoIP systems data packets. It is an older 3com NBX phone system.

If I reconfigure the devices to talk over actual VAPs rather than the WDS system ("WorkGroup Bridge"), will this allow QoS to function? Since then each device would be a client rather than a WDS VAP connected to each other (that the QoS doesnt seem to trigger on??) Id rather not do this since WDS works so well and it is the recommended system (as far as I have read)